# creationTime without timestamp in Java

Tags: java, time, format, creation

EDIT: I want to take a file's creation time but without timestamp.
My code is:

```
Path path = Paths.get(selectedFile.toURI());
BasicFileAttributes attr;
attr = Files.readAttributes(path, BasicFileAttributes.class);
System.out.println("Creation date: " + attr.creationTime());
```

Output:

```
Creation date: 2013-07-25T13:52:23.043207Z
```

How can I do to have only: `Creation date: 2013-07-25`? 
When I use `SimpleDateFormat`, it return me an error:
for example if I use (like I've seen in this forum):

```
Calendar c = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
String s = String.format("Duke's Birthday: %1$tm %1$te,%1$tY", attr.creationTime);
System.out.println("duke: " +s);
```

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Answer (score 1):

What returns `creationTime()` is a [`FileTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/FileTime.html) which is not supported by a `SimpleDateFormat` that is why it fails, you need to convert it first to a [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) thanks to the method [`toMillis()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/FileTime.html#toMillis--) as next

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
System.out.printf(
    "Creation date: %s%n", format.format(new Date(attr.creationTime().toMillis()))
);
```

**NB:** It fails with a `String` format for the same reason (`FileTime` not supported).

Comment: I simply used:
String output = data.substring(0, 10);  
...it seems to work!

Comment: yes it will work for this particular date format since it is stated into the Javadoc that [FileTime#toString()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/FileTime.html#toString--) will be returned in ISO format. You can answer to your own question

Answer (score 1):

`creationTime` returns `FileTime`. We can get the `instance` or `mills`  from it.

```
FileTime ft = attr.creationTime();
```

convert to date

```
Instant ins = ft.toInstant();
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(ins, ZoneId.systemDefault());
LocalDate ld = ldt.toLocalDate();
```

or

```
LocalDate.ofEpochDay(ft.toMillis());
```

Comment: Note that the OP seems to be asking for the date in UTC time zone - although your suggestion probably makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

If `selectedFile` is of type `java.io.File` you could do it like

```
long lastModifiedMillis = selectedFile.lastModified();
Date lastModifiedDate = new Date(lastModifiedMillis);
String s = String.format("Duke's Birthday: %1$tY-%1$tm-%1$td", lastModifiedDate);
System.out.println("duke: " + s);
```